# Can demorgan law be an example of distributive property?

Tags: math, logic, operators

If I am not wrong then the Demorgan law is:

> (A^B)~ = ~Av~B

And distributive property is:

> (AvB)vC = (AvC)vB

I was wondering if demorgan law could be the example of distributive property? If not then why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure the question really belongs here but let's give it an answer.

A distributive property is

> (A or B) and C  <=> (A and C) or (B and C)
>
> (A and B) or C <=> (A or C) and (B or C)

What you stated is associativity.

In De Morgan's law you only have two propositions (A and B) and the negation operator. So you cannot say it is distributive or associative.